# Conditionally display select values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this, but here's the use case:

In my **accounts.rb** model, I have this:

```
Account_Types = ["Checking", "Savings"]
```

So that when a user goes to select that accounts type in the view, it's normalized:

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Type of Account
    <p>Checking or Savings</p></label>
    <%= f.select(:accounttype, Account::Account_Types) %>
  </div>
```

Basically, I want to break Account_Types into two:

```
Savings_Account_Types = ["Checking", "Savings"]
Retirement_Account_Types = ["401k", "Roth IRA"]
```

My Question: When I link to the view..

```
<%= link_to(new_account_path) do %>
```

**is there a way/syntax to pass in a variable that would tell the model which _Account_Type to display?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better practice to use two separate controller/views with partials for the common sections.

But yes, you can do what you want.  If you say

```
<%= link_to new_account_path(:account_type => :savings) do %>
```

then the URL will be something like:

```
accounts/new?account_type=savings
```

And in the controller action `new`, you can use `params[:account_type]` to set a variable in the controller and finally use this in the view to select one or the other list to render.  You should get this behavior without route changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to the route

In routes

```
match '/accounts/:account_type/new', to:'accounts#new', via: :get
```

In view

```
<%= link_to new_account_path("Savings") %>
# /accounts/Savings/new
```

In Controller

```
account_types = Account.send("#{params[:account_type]_Account_Type")
```